# Why is there an extra(unwanted) column being created in my database, and how to fix it? - ASP.NET Core

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I am currently trying to create a table `QuestiontoCourses` into my database. This table should consist of a composite primary key from the values `QuestId` and `CourseId`, which are both foreign keys relating to the tables `Question` and `Course`.
However whenever I add a migration for it, an extra column called `QuestionQuestId` gets created and becomes the foreign key, and `QuestId` is not being considered a foreign key.

My Question Class does contain `QuestId`.

I have attempted manually changing both the database and migrations, but when running this statement `QuestiontoCoursesList = _context.QuestiontoCourses.ToList();`, an error occurs saying that `QuestionQuestId` cannot be found.

This is on a `.cs` file. My program is on ASP.NET 6.0 Core Web App.

I am a student with basic knowledge on ASP.NET Core, and on how to solve this issue, therefore as much of a simplified explanation would be very appreciated.

Here is my code for my `QuestiontoCourses.cs` model:

```
namespace AQA_A_Level_CS_NEA__Suvat_Solver_.Models
{
    public class QuestiontoCourses
    {
        public Question Question { get; set; }
        public int QuestId { get; set; }

        public Course Course { get; set; }
        public int CourseId { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Here is my code for the `Question` class:

```
namespace AQA_A_Level_CS_NEA__Suvat_Solver_.Models
{
    public class Question
    {
        public int QuestId { get; set; }

        public string Difficulty { get; set; }
        public char AnswType { get; set; }
        public float AnswTrue { get; set; }
        public string QuestDetails { get; set; }
        public string QuestSolved { get; set; }

        public List<QuestiontoCourses> QuestiontoCourses { get; set; }

    }
}
```

Here is my code for the Migration from the `QuestiontoCourses.cs` model:

```
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations;

#nullable disable

namespace AQA_A_Level_CS_NEA__Suvat_Solver_.Migrations
{
    public partial class QuestionCourseRelation : Migration
    {
        protected override void Up(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder)
        {
            migrationBuilder.CreateTable(
                name: "QuestiontoCourses",
                columns: table => new
                {
                    QuestId = table.Column<int>(type: "int", nullable: false),
                    CourseId = table.Column<int>(type: "int", nullable: false),
                    QuestionQuestId = table.Column<int>(type: "int", nullable: false)
                },
                constraints: table =>
                {
                    table.PrimaryKey("PK_QuestiontoCourses", x => new { x.QuestId, x.CourseId });
                    table.ForeignKey(
                        name: "FK_QuestiontoCourses_Courses_CourseId",
                        column: x => x.CourseId,
                        principalTable: "Courses",
                        principalColumn: "CourseId",
                        onDelete: ReferentialAction.Cascade);
                    table.ForeignKey(
                        name: "FK_QuestiontoCourses_Question_QuestionQuestId",
                        column: x => x.QuestionQuestId,
                        principalTable: "Question",
                        principalColumn: "QuestId",
                        onDelete: ReferentialAction.Cascade);
                });

            migrationBuilder.CreateIndex(
                name: "IX_QuestiontoCourses_CourseId",
                table: "QuestiontoCourses",
                column: "CourseId");

            migrationBuilder.CreateIndex(
                name: "IX_QuestiontoCourses_QuestionQuestId",
                table: "QuestiontoCourses",
                column: "QuestionQuestId");
        }

        protected override void Down(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder)
        {
            migrationBuilder.DropTable(
                name: "QuestiontoCourses");
        }
    }
}
```

Here is my code for `ApplicationDbContext.cs`:

```
namespace AQA_A_Level_CS_NEA__Suvat_Solver_.Data
{
    using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
    using AQA_A_Level_CS_NEA__Suvat_Solver_.Models;
    public class ApplicationDbContext : DbContext
    {

        public ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext> options)
            : base(options)
        {

        }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            modelBuilder.Entity<Question>()
            .HasKey(c => c.QuestId);
            modelBuilder.Entity<UsertoCourses>()
            .HasKey(c => new { c.UserId, c.CourseId });
            modelBuilder.Entity<QuestiontoCourses>()
            .HasKey(c => new { c.QuestId, c.CourseId });
        }

        public DbSet<User> User { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Course> Courses { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Question> Question { get; set; }
        public DbSet<UsertoCourses> UsertoCourses { get; set; }
        public DbSet<QuestiontoCourses> QuestiontoCourses { get; set; }
    }
}
```

For reference, here is the code for the `ApplicationDbContextModelSnapshot.cs` migration:

```
// <auto-generated />
using AQA_A_Level_CS_NEA__Suvat_Solver_.Data;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.ValueConversion;

#nullable disable

namespace AQA_A_Level_CS_NEA__Suvat_Solver_.Migrations
{
    [DbContext(typeof(ApplicationDbContext))]
    partial class ApplicationDbContextModelSnapshot : ModelSnapshot
    {
        protected override void BuildModel(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
#pragma warning disable 612, 618
            modelBuilder
                .HasAnnotation("ProductVersion", "6.0.8")
                .HasAnnotation("Relational:MaxIdentifierLength", 128);

            SqlServerModelBuilderExtensions.UseIdentityColumns(modelBuilder, 1L, 1);

            modelBuilder.Entity("AQA_A_Level_CS_NEA__Suvat_Solver_.Models.Course", b =>
                {
                    b.Property<int>("CourseId")
                        .ValueGeneratedOnAdd()
                        .HasColumnType("int");

                    SqlServerPropertyBuilderExtensions.UseIdentityColumn(b.Property<int>("CourseId"), 1L, 1);

                    b.Property<string>("CourseName")
                        .IsRequired()
                        .HasColumnType("nvarchar(max)");

                    b.HasKey("CourseId");

                    b.ToTable("Courses");
                });

            modelBuilder.Entity("AQA_A_Level_CS_NEA__Suvat_Solver_.Models.Question", b =>
                {
                    b.Property<int>("QuestId")
                        .ValueGeneratedOnAdd()
                        .HasColumnType("int");

                    SqlServerPropertyBuilderExtensions.UseIdentityColumn(b.Property<int>("QuestId"), 1L, 1);

                    b.Property<float>("AnswTrue")
                        .HasColumnType("real");

                    b.Property<string>("AnswType")
                        .IsRequired()
                        .HasColumnType("nvarchar(1)");

                    b.Property<string>("Difficulty")
                        .IsRequired()
                        .HasColumnType("nvarchar(max)");

                    b.Property<string>("QuestDetails")
                        .IsRequired()
                        .HasColumnType("nvarchar(max)");

                    b.Property<string>("QuestSolved")
                        .IsRequired()
                        .HasColumnType("nvarchar(max)");

                    b.HasKey("QuestId");

                    b.ToTable("Question");
                });

            modelBuilder.Entity("AQA_A_Level_CS_NEA__Suvat_Solver_.Models.QuestiontoCourses", b =>
                {
                    b.Property<int>("QuestId")
                        .HasColumnType("int");

                    b.Property<int>("CourseId")
                        .HasColumnType("int");

                    b.Property<int>("QuestionQuestId")
                        .HasColumnType("int");

                    b.HasKey("QuestId", "CourseId");

                    b.HasIndex("CourseId");

                    b.HasIndex("QuestionQuestId");

                    b.ToTable("QuestiontoCourses");
                });

            modelBuilder.Entity("AQA_A_Level_CS_NEA__Suvat_Solver_.Models.User", b =>
                {
                    b.Property<int>("UserId")
                        .ValueGeneratedOnAdd()
                        .HasColumnType("int");

                    SqlServerPropertyBuilderExtensions.UseIdentityColumn(b.Property<int>("UserId"), 1L, 1);

                    b.Property<int>("UserCorrectAnsw")
                        .HasColumnType("int");

                    b.Property<string>("UserName")
                        .IsRequired()
                        .HasColumnType("nvarchar(max)");

                    b.Property<string>("UserPass")
                        .IsRequired()
                        .HasColumnType("nvarchar(max)");

                    b.Property<int>("UserTotalAnsw")
                        .HasColumnType("int");

                    b.HasKey("UserId");

                    b.ToTable("User");
                });

            modelBuilder.Entity("AQA_A_Level_CS_NEA__Suvat_Solver_.Models.UsertoCourses", b =>
                {
                    b.Property<int>("UserId")
                        .HasColumnType("int");

                    b.Property<int>("CourseId")
                        .HasColumnType("int");

                    b.HasKey("UserId", "CourseId");

                    b.HasIndex("CourseId");

                    b.ToTable("UsertoCourses");
                });

            modelBuilder.Entity("AQA_A_Level_CS_NEA__Suvat_Solver_.Models.QuestiontoCourses", b =>
                {
                    b.HasOne("AQA_A_Level_CS_NEA__Suvat_Solver_.Models.Course", "Course")
                        .WithMany("QuestiontoCourses")
                        .HasForeignKey("CourseId")
                        .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade)
                        .IsRequired();

                    b.HasOne("AQA_A_Level_CS_NEA__Suvat_Solver_.Models.Question", "Question")
                        .WithMany("QuestiontoCourses")
                        .HasForeignKey("QuestionQuestId")
                        .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade)
                        .IsRequired();

                    b.Navigation("Course");

                    b.Navigation("Question");
                });

            modelBuilder.Entity("AQA_A_Level_CS_NEA__Suvat_Solver_.Models.UsertoCourses", b =>
                {
                    b.HasOne("AQA_A_Level_CS_NEA__Suvat_Solver_.Models.Course", "Course")
                        .WithMany("UsertoCourses")
                        .HasForeignKey("CourseId")
                        .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade)
                        .IsRequired();

                    b.HasOne("AQA_A_Level_CS_NEA__Suvat_Solver_.Models.User", "User")
                        .WithMany("UsertoCourses")
                        .HasForeignKey("UserId")
                        .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade)
                        .IsRequired();

                    b.Navigation("Course");

                    b.Navigation("User");
                });

            modelBuilder.Entity("AQA_A_Level_CS_NEA__Suvat_Solver_.Models.Course", b =>
                {
                    b.Navigation("QuestiontoCourses");

                    b.Navigation("UsertoCourses");
                });

            modelBuilder.Entity("AQA_A_Level_CS_NEA__Suvat_Solver_.Models.Question", b =>
                {
                    b.Navigation("QuestiontoCourses");
                });

            modelBuilder.Entity("AQA_A_Level_CS_NEA__Suvat_Solver_.Models.User", b =>
                {
                    b.Navigation("UsertoCourses");
                });
#pragma warning restore 612, 618
        }
    }
}
```

Many Thanks.

Comment: does your Question class contains QuestId or reference of Quest ?

Comment: Yes, my Question class contains QuestId. Apologies for not adding that with my question.

Comment: This is because your foreign key property name and your navigation property name don't line up, it should be `[FullNameOfClassReferenced]Id` so `QuestionId` but you have `QuestId` so Entity Framework Core thinks you don't have a foreign key property on your model and silently creates one as a [shadow property](https://www.learnentityframeworkcore.com/model/shadow-properties), if you really want it to be `QuestId` you need to tell Entity Framework Core how to map it like how mehrabadi shows in [their answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73383300/9363973)

Comment: Generally speaking, the consensus for a few decades now has been: do not abbreviate. We have the technology, we can spare the bytes. Write out your variable, table and column names in plain and correct English. It will save you so much trouble. Especially if the abbreviations you pick aren't actually abbreviations but just different words with a different meaning it gets confusing. For humans and machines. Don't save 3 bytes and confuse your readers. Write properly, it saves time for everyone involved.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In ef core, the table name must be the same as the table key name so that it can be recognized.
For example :

```
public class QuestiontoCourses
{
    public Question Question { get; set; }
    public int QuestionId { get; set; }
}
```

If you don't want to use this name, you can use fluent api

for example :

```
public class QuestiontoCoursesConfigurations : IEntityTypeConfiguration<QuestiontoCourses>
{
    public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<QuestiontoCourses> builder)
    {
        builder.HasOne(x => x.Question)
            .WithMany(x => x.QuestiontoCourses)
            .HasForeignKey(x => x.QuestId);
    }
}
```

Comment: *"The table name must be the same as the table key name"* statement is incorrect. Conventional patterns (they are more than one) for property names recognized as FK are clearly explained in the [official docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relationships?tabs=fluent-api%2Cfluent-api-simple-key%2Csimple-key)

Answer (score 2):

From .NET Core 5 you dont need to manually specify the relation table in a many-to-many relationship. In your case you should just add the relations directly as list in your classes as

```
public class Question
{
    ..
    public ICollection<Course> Courses { get; set; }
}

public class Course
{
    ..
    public ICollection<Question> Questions { get; set; }
}
```

read more on the docs [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relationships?tabs=fluent-api%2Cfluent-api-simple-key%2Csimple-key#many-to-many)